# Solution that minimizes the sum of squared errors, with quadratic constraints

Tags: quadratic-forms, matrix-equations, closed-form-expressions, least-squares

Given symmetric and positive definite $n \times n$ (real) matrices $A_1, \dots, A_m$ and $b_1, \dots, b_m \in {\Bbb R}^{n}$, I am trying to find the solution with the least sum of squared errors of the following system of equations in $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$.

$$\begin{cases}
\sqrt{x^\top A_1 x} &= \sqrt{b_1^\top b_1}\\
%
&\vdots\\
%
\sqrt{x^\top A_m x} &= \sqrt{b_m^\top b_m}
%
\end{cases}$$

where $m>n$. This optimization problem can be formulated as follows.

$$x^{*} := \arg\min_x \sum_{i=1}^m \left( \sqrt{x^\top A_i x} - \sqrt{b_i^\top b_i}\right)^2.$$

Does a non-iterative (closed-form) solution exist?

Comment: How large are $m$ and $n$?  Have you tried to square both sides, take the gradient of the quartic and *symbolically* solve a system of cubic equations?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo thanks for the feedback. $n\in\{1\,..\,4\}$, $m=6$ can be assumed. Regarding the squaring option to both sides, I feel that it would change where the minima are located, something that is not desirable in this specific problem. I have also tried the symbolic option without luck.

Comment: Why would changing "where the minima are located" worry you?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo in this case what worries me is that higher deviations of certain datapoints $\sqrt{x^\top A_i x} - y_i$, would be penalized more strongly. In the problem I'm interested about, there can be outliers which would have a stronger influence in the solution. Ideally they can be filtered out, but it would be great if the problem can be solved without that risk.